# How to ignore the escaping \ python list?

Tags: python, list, escaping

I want to ignore the escape character in the following code.

```
>>> a=['\%']
>>> print a
['\\%']
```

I want to output like `['\%']`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what you're seeing here? In python, `'\\%' == '\%'` - both represent a backslash character followed by a percent character.

Answer (score 8):

Using `string_escape`, `unicode_escape` encoding (See [Python Specific Encodings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)):

```
>>> a = ['\%']
>>> print str(a).decode('string_escape')
['\%']
>>> print str(a).decode('unicode_escape')
['\%']
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of manual ways:

```
>>> a=['\%']
>>> print "['{}']".format(a[0])
['\%']
>>> print "['%s']" % a[0]
['\%']
```

Or more generally:

```
>>> a=['\%', '\+']
>>> print '[{}]'.format(', '.join("'{}'".format(i) for i in a))
['\%', '\+']
>>> print '[%s]' % ', '.join("'%s'" % i for i in a)
['\%', '\+']
```